# Android: Retrieve array position depending on item value?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array (of class):

`ArrayList<MyInvoiceItems> list_items = new ArrayList<MyInvoiceItems>();`

Here is my class:

```
class MyInvoiceItems {

private Integer item_key;
private String item_mkat;
private Integer item_num;
private Double item_cost;
private String item_desc;
private Integer taken;.......}
```

My array has dynamic size and sometimes I know the item_key or item_desc, How Can I get the 'position' of **list_items** based on variable (item_key...) value?

Do I have to do a loop or there is any query or function that I can call?

Comment: you have to loop and check if the values are the same. If the order doesn't matter you could use an HashMap, with key `item_key`.

Comment: I prefer class because I have other implantation inside it: functions...setter, getter...

Comment: you can have `HashMap<Integer, MyInvoiceItems>`, if you were referring to my hashmap 's comment